# No suitable JDBC driver found for database type: PostgreSQL with Teamcity when jar file is there

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, teamcity

I have been trying to set up a TeamCity instance in Docker, and when I try to migrate from the internal DB - which I successfully removed - TeamCity doesn't find the JDBC driver for PostgreSQL with the error: `No suitable JDBC driver found for database type: PostgreSQL`. The Docker container has the `TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH` set to `/data/teamcity_server/datadir`, and

`$TEAMCITY_DATA_PATH/lib/` contains this:

```
/data/teamcity_server/datadir/lib/
└── jdbc
    └── postgresql-42.2.5.jar
```

all in accordance with the mother-os's files mapped to that of the container.

The database.properties file in case it's needed:

```
connectionUrl=jdbc\:postgresql\://mydbserver.com\:5432
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question, though still not answered. I've bumped into it while trying to find solution to the exactly the same problem, so let me leave a solution for anyone running into this.

The root of the issue lies in the incorrect `connectionUrl`, according to TeamCity documentation it should include database name at the end, e.g.:

```
connectionUrl=jdbc:postgresql://mydbserver.com:5432/teamcitydb
```

The error is 'a bit' misleading here. it's not about missing jar, but about connection configuration.